# Truffle still using old solc compiler even after updating truffle-config.js

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity, truffle, ganache

I am having a problem where truffle is still using old solidity compiler (- solc: 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang) even though i specified in my truffle-config.js to use version: '0.8.4'.

```
 compilers: {
  solc: {
    version: '0.8.4',
  },
},
```

to run truffle i use `npx truffle` , my `npx truffle -v` give the following:

`Truffle v5.5.28 (core: 5.5.28) Ganache v7.4.0 Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js) Node v14.16.1 Web3.js v1.7.4`

i tried to reinstall truffle with @latest still same issue, tried to install solc latest version and still truffle isnt picking up the new solidity compiler

i also want to state that truffle init or any command don't work for me so i sue npx. could this be a reeason?

any help?

Comment: did you save the file after you made changes

Comment: Yes of course i did

Comment: i also want to state that truffle init or any command don't work for me so i sue npx. could this be a reeason?

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe how dumb this was! I spend 4 hours fixing this and I stumbled upon this article https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/5073

I had the

```
compilers: {
  solc: {
    version: '0.8.4',
  },
},
```

inside the

```
  networks: {
    development: {
...
    },
  },
```

Don't ask me how!

This is insane. Anyways keep this here maybe someone like me or the person who posted about this too had the same issue.